# Spring Deferred result lost http session

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, asynchronous

I´m using a Tomcat 7 with Spring MVC and Spring security in async mode.

Then I´m using DeferredResult to make async request. The mechanism works fine, but the problem is than when the deferredResult make the setResult() and return the promise, I lost all my session, and my next request give me a 403 forbidden since I dont have my authentication on my SecurityContextHolder.

I guess is because the return of the promise is done in another thread that dont has the session.

Somebody can put me in the right direction here please.

Solution: onCompletion callback method I pass the session that I put when I create the deferredResult in a map.

```
      deferredResult.onCompletion(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            request.getSession().setAttribute(SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT, securityContextContainer.get(deferredResult));
            securityContextContainer.remove(deferredResult);
        }
    });
```

Comment: If you indeed resolved your own problem post it as answer and accept it, don't append it to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: onCompletion callback method I pass the session that I put when I create the deferredResult in a map.

```
  deferredResult.onCompletion(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        request.getSession().setAttribute(SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT, securityContextContainer.get(deferredResult));
        securityContextContainer.remove(deferredResult);
    }
});
```