# How to attach async job to a HTTP session?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session, asynchronous

I need to run some time-consuming task from a controller. To do it I have implemented an `@Async` method in my service so that the controller can return immediately (for example with `202 Created` status).

The problem is that the task need access to some session-scoped beans. With this approach I am getting `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name (...): Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread (...)`.

The same result is when I manually create an ExecutionService instead of `@Async`.

Is it possible to somehow make a worker thread attached to the current session?

---

EDIT
The purpose is to implement a bulk operation, providing a way to monitor the status of processing. Something like described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28787774/718590

If I run it synchronously, there will be no indication of the status (how many items processed), and a request timeout may occur.

Comment: can you share more details? do you really need it during async execution? can you just extract needed info beforehand? or you just need to store result afterwards like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29716119/spring-deferred-result-lost-http-session ?

Comment: @sodik I've added more details to the question.

Comment: @AndreiI I'm not attaching a Thread to the session. It's Spring that maintains connection between threads and the session.

Answer (score 2):

If I correctly understand, you want to be able to start a long time asynchronous processing from a spring web application, and be able to follow advancement of processing from the session that started it. And the processing could use beans contained in the session.

For a good separation of concerns, I would never have an asynchronous thread know a session. The session is related to HTTP and can be destroyed at any time before the thread can finish (or even begin in race conditions) its processing.

IMHO, a correct design would be to create a class containing all the informations shared between the web part and the asynchronous processing : the status (whatever it can be), the user that started processing if is is relevant and every other relevant piece of information. In your controller (of preferently in the service method called by the controller) you prepare an object of that class, and pass it to the `@Async` method. Then before returning, the controller stores the object in session. That way :

- the asynchronous processing has all its required information, even is the session is destroyed later. It does not need to know the session and only cares for its processing and updates its status
- the session of the web application knows that the asynchronous processing  is running, know how it was started and what is the current status

It can be adapted to your real problem, but this should meet your requirements.

Comment: Well, the suggested design looks good, but needs significant changes in the design of the whole application. I'm not writing a new application, just adding an HTTP API to an existing application.
It is probably OK to fail the processing if the session is gone - tasks are user-initiated and there is currently no requirement to maintain processing even when the user logged out. It might be a nice feature, though.